# Chrome extension search_url pass {searchTerm} as a post param value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Default search works only with get method, I would like to use post method and pass all query parameters using the post body (especially the `{searchTerm}`).

I tried to use the `search_url_post_params` property, but it looks like it's not working.

How do I include post parameters in the default search url of a chrome extension? Here is the override settings in my manifest.json

```
"chrome_settings_overrides": {
    "search_provider": {
      "is_default": true,
      "encoding": "UTF-8",
      "keyword": "My Extension",
      "name": "My Extension",
      "search_url": "http://myapp.com/search",
      "search_url_post_params": "source=default_search&query={searchTerms}"
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://crbug.com/268698

Comment: thanks for your comment. is there other way to make default search using post request(using {searchTerm})?